# Handle missing values based on other column values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'City': ['Cambridge','','Boston','Washignton','','Tampa',
'Danvers','Miami','Cambridge','Miami','','Washington'], 'State': ['MA','DC','MA',
'DC','MA','FL','MA','FL','MA','FL','FL','DC']})
```

As we can see in the above df, I have two columns "City" and "State". There are 3 cities with '' (No values). I want to assign a value to those missing values in cities. The assignment has to be done in the following way - City which exists the max number of times for a particular state should be assigned to the missing value for that particular state. For example: The 2nd missing city is corresponding to the state MA. Now if I carefully look at the data, "Cambridge" is the city which occurs the most number of times for the state MA. Therefore, that missing value should be replaced with "Cambridge".

Following the same trend, 1st missing city should be Washington, 2nd should be Cambridge and 3rd should be Miami.

How will I accomplish this task using pandas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
top_cities = {}
for state in np.unique(df.State):
    cities = [city for city in df[df.State==state].City.values if city]
    top_cities[state] = max(set(cities), key=cities.count)

new_cities = []
for city, state in df.values:
    if city:
        new_cities.append(city)
    else:
        new_cities.append(top_cities[state])

df['City'] = new_cities
```

[image]

Comment: Runs fine for me with python 3.5 and pandas version 0.19.0

Answer (score 3):

IIUC

```
df.update(df.replace('', np.nan).set_index('State', append=True) \
    .groupby(level='State').City \
    .apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x.value_counts().idxmax())) \
    .reset_index('State', drop=True))
df
```

[image]

---

***reference code***
***note:*** additional column `A` is original `City` column making it easier to see where cities get filled in.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'City': ['Cambridge','','Boston','Washignton','','Tampa',
                 'Danvers','Miami','Cambridge','Miami','','Washington'],
        'State': ['MA','DC','MA','DC','MA','FL',
                  'MA','FL','MA','FL','FL','DC'],
        'A': ['Cambridge','','Boston','Washignton','','Tampa',
              'Danvers','Miami','Cambridge','Miami','','Washington']})

df.update(df.replace('', np.nan).set_index('State', append=True) \
    .groupby(level='State').City \
    .apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x.value_counts().idxmax())) \
    .reset_index('State', drop=True))
df
```

[image]

Comment: The piece of code provided by you works, and displays the same output for me. But when I print all the columns of df, the changes aren't made there. What could be the problem?

Comment: you need to assign what I've done to `df`.  I'll update my post.

Comment: Ok that part worked. But my df also has other columns. If I run above piece of code, it replaces my whole df with just above 2 columns. I want other columns to be same

Comment: @user6461192 updated post to not mess with other columns.

Comment: Now it retains other columns, but the necessary changes aren't made to the 'city' column. The values are still NaN.

Comment: @user6461192 i've updated my post with a reference to exactly what i've run.  If this doesn't work for you, it's either a version issue or something in your data that I'd suggest you share.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126857/discussion-between-user6461192-and-pirsquared).

Comment: Just a small change. We need to update city column of df. This works: df.City.update(df.replace('', np.nan).set_index('State', append=True) \
    .groupby(level='State').City \
    .apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x.value_counts().idxmax())) \
    .reset_index('State', drop=True))

Comment: @piRSquared I know this old, but I have a related question. How would this look if there was an additional column 'zip' and we wanted to fill in city based on 'zip' if 'zip' is available. If not, then use 'state'.